# JQuery/Javascript not properly loading a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

PHP Version 7.0

JQuery Version 3.1.0

You can see that the everything above the code is simply copied and pasted every five seconds rather than refreshing.

The intention is to refresh the include every five seconds.

Website: http://ssmsportal.cf/pages/incomingCalls.php

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ServerSide Moderation Services</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/tablesStyles.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/incomingCallsStyle.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


    <title>Whats Up?</title>

    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <?php include '../includes/header.php'; ?>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="logRegArea">
                <article class="callsContent" style='padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;'>
                    <header>
                        <h2 class="loginArea" style="text-align:center">Incoming Calls:</h2>
                    </header>
                    <content>
                        <div id="login">
                        <?php include '../includes/incomingCalls.php'; ?>
                        </div>
                        <script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                setInterval(function () {
                                    $('#login').load('../includes/incomingCalls.php')
                                }, 5000);
                            });
                        </script>
                    </content>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>This website was developed by ROBLOX user: <a href="https://www.roblox.com/users/8869935/profile" title="Made by: wattleman">wattleman</a></p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal behavior of the load function.

You should instead try:

```
$.get("../includes/incomingCalls.php", function(data) {
     $("#login").html(data);
});
```

Comment: I assume that I can replace $(document) down? If not what do I replace? And where does a timer go, or is it live?

Comment: You just have to change your load function for this one. Keep the rest, such as timer and document ready.

Comment: If you go to the website, it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Ok, so your page is named incomingCall.php and you are calling the same page in the jQuery function? So what other behavior do you expect?

Comment: The page and the include are called the same thing, but in separate places.

Comment: What is in the page you are loading?

Comment: Interesting! I guess it took a minute for the FTP on the website to work! Perfect results! Thank you!